# What does the $ in property name mean in ActionScript 3 (or JavaScript)

Tags: java, javascript, actionscript-3

I saw this code recently,

```
    public function CursorManager($target:InteractiveObject, $cursor:String) {
        _target=$target;
        _cursor=$cursor;
        _target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onOver);
        _target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onOut);
    }
```

Why is this person using the $ in the parameter $target? Does it hold any significant meaning? 
I've seen this in JavaScript as well.

UPDATE:
Is it possible it was used to denote static or constant variable? It does not appear to be used as static in this example.

UPDATE 2:
I found some code in the Flex UIComponent class that uses $width, $height. I've added an answer.

Comment: Why would you pass a static or a constant variable like this? (makes no sense to me, personally). It is simply just to point out it is a parameter/local variable.

Comment: I agree, in this case it doesn't make any sense. I've seen it used as static a few times but I've also seen it used to denote a super variable in a base class.

Comment: It's required by PHP variable declaration. People using this in AS3 might have some PHP background. Other than that it has no meaning and fit no known as3 coding convention.

Answer (score 4):

In this example I would say author uses $ prefix to identify variable that comes from outside (function parameter) and prefix _ to identify variable that belongs to the this function or entire class.

So the answer is **NO, it doesn't hold any significant meaning. It is done for convenience only**. You may want to look into code naming conventions to learn more about that.

Comment: I thought variable names could only be letters and numbers and underscore but had to start with a letter or underscore. It seems dollar sign is OK to use and hold no meaning.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts In AS3 you can start with underscore _ and dollar sign $ as well.

Comment: I will just add: it is rather uncommon to use dollar sign. Underscores are used for class variables (useful for various IDEs - they are listed on the top of the code-hinting list).

Comment: By naming conventions static variable usually in capital letters. Great example: MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT. ROLL_OUT is a STATIC variable of MouseEvent class. In this case we need to see what's outside the function to be able to tell what _ stands for. $ - definitely not static here.

Comment: @MaxGram Please don't confuse static variables with constants. ROLL_OUT is a constant. Logically a constant is static indeed but not every static variable is a constant. Constants are capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

When I code JavaScript I use this notation for jQuery-Objects like this:

```
var $target = $(event.target);
$target.hide();
```

Others may use this differently.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that with JQuery. It seems they have taken over the single dollar sign for their own nefarious uses.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts in jQuery it does, however, have a purpose - you are reminding yourself/other developers that the variable holds a jQuery object so you can call jQuery methods on it, without wrapping it with $(...) (again).

Answer (score 0):

As Max stated, "the answer is NO, it doesn't hold any significant meaning. It is done for convenience only." but I want to add more. It is not treated any differently by the compiler (as far as I know) but in Flex it is used to signify a base property, it's final and cannot be overridden that is a reflection of a native player implementation.

For example, in the property $scaleX it states:

```
/**
 *  This property allows access to the Player's native implementation
 *  of the <code>scaleX</code> property, which can be useful since components
 *  can override <code>scaleX</code> and thereby hide the native implementation.
 *  Note that this "base property" is final and cannot be overridden,
 *  so you can count on it to reflect what is happening at the player level.
 */
```

The $width property is the same:

```
/**
 *  @private
 *  This property allows access to the Player's native implementation
 *  of the 'width' property, which can be useful since components
 *  can override 'width' and thereby hide the native implementation.
 *  Note that this "base property" is final and cannot be overridden,
 *  so you can count on it to reflect what is happening at the player level.
 */

mx_internal final function get $width():Number
{
    return super.width; // UIComponent extends FlexSprite which extends Sprite
}
```

All of the properties that begin with $ in the UIComponent class reflect these attributes.